# VBA code to scan through a comma separated value in a cell and retrieve lookup value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario where I have to read through values in one cell which is comma separated and retrieve only values from that array to match with a particular lookup value. For eg:

[image]

So what I need is a function to retrieve all **Task**(or any other issuetype which could vary) from row 2 Links column

expected result: Against A2 I want to retrieve A4 and A6

Comment: Why `A4` and `A6` though? Because they are values present in the first column?

Comment: And why does `A3` have the values `A4, A6` when `A6` isn't present in its `Links`? This question needs some clarification one how you are getting these `Result(Task)` values for each row.

Comment: Yes that is correct. A4 and A6 appears on the first result because they are the only Task that is available in its links. And apologies. You are right, A3 must have only A4

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is something I modified so that you could customize it to any lookup value

Function GetLinkedItem(link As String, targetLinkType As String)
Dim temp(0 To 0) As String
    GetLinkedItem = "None"
    If Trim(link) = "" Then Exit Function

```
Dim links() As String, i As Long
links = Split(link, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(links)
    'select the links that are targetLinkType
    Dim j As Long

    j = GetRow(Trim(links(i)))

    If Sheets("Data").Cells(j, ISUUETYPE_COL) = targetLinkType Then

        temp(0) = temp(0) & " " & Sheets("Data").Cells(j, ID_COL) & ","

    End If
   GetLinkedItem = Join(temp, ",")
   Next i
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UDF to perform this lookup. In a new module in your VBE, paste the following:

```
Function getTasks(tasklist As Range, availabletasks As Range) As String
    'tasklist is the incoming array in Column C
    'availabletasks is the stuff in Column A

    'Array for output
    Dim tasks() As String: ReDim tasks(0 To 0)

    'Loop through each item in taslist using an array
    For Each task In Split(tasklist.Value, ", ")

        'Search availabletasks
        If Not availabletasks.Find(task) Is Nothing Then
            'pop the array
            If tasks(0) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve tasks(0 To UBound(tasks) + 1)
            tasks(UBound(tasks)) = task
        End If
    Next

    'Return what we found
    getTasks = Join(tasks, ", ")

End Function
```

Now in your spreadsheet you can use this function just like a regular formula:

```
=getTasks(C1,$A$1:$A$6)
```

Where `C1` has the list like `A4, A25, A22, A6, A29, A42` and `$A$1:$A$6` are just like your example Column A. This will return `A4, A6`

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I added the code in a new module and used the function as formula. I was getting just 1 value instead of 2(Just got A4 and not A6).

Comment: The VBA is set up to split on a comma followed by a space so inure that each value is split like that in column C like `A1, A2, A6, A29`

Comment: I removed the space and it worked, Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: That's great news!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much. I added the code in a new module and used the function as formula. I was getting just 1 value instead of 2(Just got A4 and not A6).
[image]